# Splitting or Something

Tags: excel

I am using MS Excel.

I have two Data sheets (Comma Separated).

Data sheet 1 contains various records of data but importantly post codes.

Data sheet 2 contains the first part of a post code (So either 1 character or 2 characters) and the region of England those post codes are linked to.

I need to check the first part of the post code in data sheet 2 with the whole post code and add the corresponding region from data sheet 2 to the record on data sheet 1.

I'm sure V-Lookup or Match might work, but I really can't get my head around it.

EDIT

Here is an example

Datasheet 1 - [image]

Datasheet 2 - [image]

Notice Scotland (South & Central) only has 1 character partial post code

Comment: could you post an example image

Comment: I'll see what I can do, the issue is the data is very sensitive, so I'll make some fake stuff but based on the same principle. Please bare with me.

Comment: dont post the orignal data just give us some dummy data to let us know how it looks like

Comment: I have edited original post.

Comment: can you tell me whether the region of england starts always with a number?

Comment: The region is the place name, no numbers at all in the region of England.

Comment: The Patial post code is allways a letter (Character) there is no numerical charcters in the partial post code. The rest of the post code will then be a number(s) then characters

Comment: I have posted the answer please check

Comment: @Macor: Was it helpful or did u find any difficulty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this would help you.

```
=IF(MATCH(VLOOKUP(MID(A2,1,1),F2:G6,2,FALSE),G2:G6,0)=1,VLOOKUP(MID(A2,1,1),F2:G6,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(MID(A2,1,2),F2:G6,2,FALSE))
```

But be careful regardingkeeping the $ sign for indexes which have to be constant.

[image]

Comment: Incase of any queries please post

Comment: I am just getting #N/A results. I have recreated what you are doing, even copied and pasted the code and put the data in the same columns but still #N/A

http://i.imgur.com/lLII4.jpg

Comment: check if match function is there or not

Comment: I am going to have to play about with it, but I can see what it supposed to happen. Thank you for your help.